# ngx-color-picker - automatic positioning

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

The color picker should open up when there's not enough space at the bottom and vice-versa.

Is this possible?

The [cpPosition] - auto doesn't work and I am using the latest version of the plugin and angular.

Any help will be appreciated.

For reference :

https://stackblitz.com/github/zefoy/ngx-color-picker/tree/master/example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

I need something of this sort:

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-nook3qRb9G4/Xd-jkGEKA_I/AAAAAAAAKl8/NJ4WePYnXiw60tirwzwYFCpQ7C0riEkcACK8BGAsYHg/s0/2019-11-28.gif

Comment: Could you provide some code implementation to look into the issue ?

Comment: @Alex: Please refer this: https://stackblitz.com/github/zefoy/ngx-color-picker/tree/master/example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: From what I see, by default it is the `auto` option used, and this might be because there is a scrollbar allowing the modal to open normally, even though it might be cropped because of the scrolling. 

I deleted the end of example you showed so that the `Toggle` button would be at the end of the page, and the modal makes the page widder to allow the full appearance of the color picker as expected by the `auto` configuration.

Is this a good example of your issue ? https://wmaibnlan.github.stackblitz.io

Comment: yes, the issue is I don't need a scrollbar to view the color picker, it should adopt the position based on the space available in the top/ bottom/ left/ right.

Comment: I have added a GIF, as this option is available for the bootstrap date picker. I think this has to come with the plugin.

Comment: I'm afraid this has to do with the way `ngx-color-picker` implements their modal. You could open an issue to have them update the library; or you could fork the project and do it yourself, but you will struggle to integrate the latest updates from the library if they ever come. 
It also might be possible to override the behavior locally in your component but I'm afraid it would be difficult; I'm not even sure it is possible.